# Proxy from org-apache-maven only in Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I want to add a proxy repository in Nexus(OSS 2.5.0 v) just from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven ( and not from the entire http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/). When I do this, the Browse index shows nothing, Browse remote shows  all contents, Browse storage is empty as expected, and routing shows the status as unsuccessful. Why does this happen? 
How can I successfully proxy from only http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven ?

Thanks

Edit: can this be done through pom file? Anybody??

Comment: You should consider update your OSS nexus to newest versions 2.13 ?

Comment: @khmarbaise do you know if I can get the solution by upgrading to 2.13 ?

Comment: You should use the routing rules for that...in general you can't limit the access to a sub folder repositories...

Comment: Can you please show the routing rules? I tried usign regex but didnt work

Answer (score 3):

You can't, that isn't a valid repository URL.  You need to proxy http://repo1.maven.org/maven2.   You can add [Routing Rules](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-routes.html#manual-routing) to control what paths Nexus will consider when looking for artifacts in the proxy, so you could limit it to /org/apache/maven that way.  But I think you will find that this won't work out very well, the pom files in that location have dependencies which are in other locations in central, so your builds will fail with that restriction.

Comment: Hi ! why do you think it isn't a valid URL? If I click on http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven, am able to see the contents under it. So it is a valid URL? With respect to your point on " the pom files in that location have dependencies which are in other locations in central, so your builds will fail with that restriction.", it is fine in my scenario. I will manually download those dependencies and provide it in my local repo for building. Thanks!